# Java Get back InputStream from String Converted by Apache IOUtils

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, ioutils

I am using library [Sharepoint-Java-API](https://gitlab.com/quantr/sharepoint/Sharepoint-Java-API) to download Files from Sharepoint.
I am able to download file but got as **String** format which is converted using `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` as

```
public static String get(Pair<String, String> token, String url) {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        getRequest.addHeader("Cookie", token.getLeft() + ";" + token.getRight());
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + ", " + url);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SPOnlineMFT.class).error(ex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now I am trying to convert it to **InputStream** and save it local file system for testing

**Caller:-**

```
String content = SPOnline.get(token, domain, url );
if (content != null) {
    File targetFile = new File("D:\\Rivian\\SharePoint\\TempDownload/"+fileName);
//  InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes("utf-8"));
    InputStream stream = IOUtils.toInputStream(content, "utf-8");
    Files.copy(stream, targetFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    System.out.println("File Downloaded")
}
```

but I am not able to read/open file e.g. MS excel file. While opening file got message as corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

Just write byte array directly into file, without converting it to utf-8 string.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path file = Path.of("D:\\SharePoint\\TempDownload/"+fileName);
Files.write(file, response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Comment: I have to return, `response.getEntity().getContent()` to caller for that, if I closed `HttpClient` in called method, content will not availavle to me.

Comment: then just keep reference to it in local variable that you can also return to caller...